# Can I modify android platform drawables without problems?

Tags: android, image, drawable, editing

For my app I need (like I think many and many devs) to customise colours and drawables; at the moment I need to customise a platform drawable (the action bar background, which for the android platform is ab_solid_light(or _dark)_holo.9.png) which can be taken from various sources (android.jar, git, etc.). In my case, I'd like to modify it from grey to another color; can I simply take it, modify it with gimp/Photoshop/similar application and include in my resources? Should I give credits to aosp in "open source licenses" section of my app? Is there a standard or conventional way to do these kind of things?

Comment: See the full Apache 2.0 license details at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 or https://tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-(apache-2.0) for a summary of the licensing agreement. TL;DR go for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tldrlegal.com link! Very useful!